# Unwanted horizontal scroll in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have been working on creating a similar image setup like here: https://readcereal.com/category/travel/ using CSS grid and I constantly encounter one issue - a horizontal scroll. I use Bootstrap for the navbar. It looks like in the attached image. Would anyone have idea why is that happening? I tried so many different CSS grid combinations and it never worked. Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UwjN.png

Comment: can you provide a simple code example demonstrating the problem? Or you can debug the html by inspecting dimensions of each div using inspector. Look for margins, borders..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should wrap your images inside an images container and then set the container to max-width: 900px or depends on what max width you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have a really simple solution for this problem

```
.row{
  width: 100%;
 }
```

It will work only for bootstrap ...you can try this one.